# Can an ETag be changed with a 304 response?

Tags: http, browser, web, etag

- Browser makes request with header `If-None-Match: "123"`
- Server returns 304 response with header `ETag: "555"`

Will subsequent browser requests for that url contain the header `If-None-Match: "123"` or `If-None-Match: "555"`? Is this behavior consistent between browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Chrome will not update the If-None-Match header when the 304 response returns a new ETag header. The browser continues using the If-None-Match: "123" on subsequent requests, even if the server returned ETag: "555" with a 304 response.